# How Can I Read A Web Browser Hidden Document Value Using IWebBrowser2 In LabVIEW?

Tags: javascript, .net, forms, labview

I've searched around the internet for a couple of hours and could not find anything related to what I'm trying to do. I wrote a HTML document that collects data from a user and stores it in a javascript array. This array is then joined together and stored as a string in a document which is hidden. Originally, I was going to transfer this string to a program I wrote in C#, but now I am using LabVIEW.

In C#, I used two simple lines of code to do what I wanted:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement hidden = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hiddenfield1");
List<latlng> data = formharvest.extract(hidden.GetAttribute("value"));
```

But now I cannot find a way to access the data that is in this hidden document. I'm using the IWebBrowser2 block to embed my HTML code in my VI. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Maybe you can use the LabVIEW web server capabilities. Can't help however no experience on this

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to start a Web server in your LabVIEW program, and serve your HTML form from it. I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to retrieve form data then, but I haven't done such thing myself.

Here's [an interesting discussion on this](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/How-to-send-a-URL-from-within-LabView/m-p/791309?view=by_date_ascending#M361394) with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand what you are doing above: in the C#, it looks like you are embedding an HTML-rendering engine in a Windows form (i.e. window).

You can embed .NET in your labview code and therefore you should be able to embed the same HTML rendering engine in a LabView VI, but you might consider changing your approach, as CharlesB suggests, to something more traditional where a server serves some HTML to a web browser, which then sends some data back to the server via HTTP GET or POST.